# HashiCorp Terraform/Vault - Why is my role max TTL configuration being ignored?

Tags: terraform, hashicorp-vault, terraform-provider-vault

I'm trying to create a database self-service role with a max TTL (time to live) of 7 days. I have two environments, both running Vault 1.12.1, and one is working as expected and the other the logins disappear after an hour. Both roles were created via the same TF code (below) so I'm thinking there must be an overriding config somewhere but not sure where to start looking.

```
#new vault mount for db user self serve
resource "vault_mount" "db" {
  path = "database-self-serve"
  type = "database"
  default_lease_ttl_seconds =  0
  max_lease_ttl_seconds = 604800
}

#Configure vault connections to databases
resource "vault_database_secret_backend_connection" "database-1" {
  backend       = vault_mount.db.path
  name          = "${var.terraform_environment}-database-1"
  allowed_roles = formatlist("mysql-database-1-%s", local.allowed_role_list)

  mysql_aurora {
    connection_url = "{{username}}:{{password}}@tcp(${local.database-1_mysql_connection_url}:3306)/"
  }
  data = {
    username = local.db_user
    password = var.connection_password
  }
  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [data]
  }
}

#configure vault roles which define the create user statements
resource "vault_database_secret_backend_role" "database-1-readonly" {
  count               = "${contains(local.allowed_role_list,"readonly") == true ? 1 : 0}"
  depends_on          = [vault_database_secret_backend_connection.database-1]
  backend             = vault_mount.db.path
  name                = "mysql-database-1-readonly"
  db_name             = "${var.terraform_environment}-database-1"
  creation_statements = ["${var.create_mysql_user}${var.readonly_mysql_permissions}"]
  default_ttl         = 604800
  max_ttl             = 604800
}
```

I've compared the Vault mount, connection, and role settings between the two environments and they match.

I've also tried setting the "vault_mount" *default_lease_ttl_seconds* to equal *max_lease_ttl_seconds*.

UPDATE:
I've tried extending the default and max_TTL as well as dropping and recreating the secrets and still no luck. When I generate new credentials, I validate they exist/work and according to the Vault Lease (image below), they should expire in 30 days but are gone after an hour.
[image: Lease]

Answer (score 0):

The `max_lease_ttl` for all Vault leases can be declared in your HCL Vault config.  More details on that [here](https://developer.hashicorp.com/vault/docs/configuration).  I would wager this is probably set to 1h in your case.

Comment: Unless I'm miss reading it, that setting should be overridden by configuring the default and max_ttl at the mount/secret level, no?